# Mediawiki: how to allow new account creation through facebook only?

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way to allow new account creations on mediawiki only through the facebook extension? I.e. I want to disable regular account creation (unless done by sysops) through Special:UserLogin/signup, while still allowing the facebook extension to automatically create new accounts as needed.

Everything I've tried so far completely blocks account creation in all cases (except for sysops). Specifically, when I disable regular account creation through wgGroupPermissions, as in:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
```

then the facebook extension throws the following error:

```
Non-string key given

Backtrace:

#0 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(1183): MessageCache->get(Array, true, false)
#1 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(1163): wfMsgGetKey(Array, true, false, true)
#2 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(1081): wfMsgReal(Array, Array)
#3 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/extensions/Facebook/FacebookUser.php(41): wfMsg(Array)
#4 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/extensions/Facebook/FacebookUser.php(327): FacebookUserException->__construct(Array, 'createaccount')
#5 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/extensions/Facebook/SpecialConnect.php(235): FacebookUser->createUser('rommel.hoop.1', '')
#6 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/includes/SpecialPageFactory.php(458): SpecialConnect->execute('ChooseName')
#7 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/includes/Wiki.php(240): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Object(Title), Object(RequestContext))
#8 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/includes/Wiki.php(640): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#9 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/includes/Wiki.php(547): MediaWiki->main()
#10 /var/www-wiki.kostumekult.com/html/index.php(57): MediaWiki->run()
#11 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
$wgFbDisableLogin = true;
```

to your LocalSettings.php.

Comment: Hmm... Pretty close. This does seem to allow facebook account creations, even when $wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;

Comment: Hmm... Pretty close. This does seem to allow facebook account creations, even when "$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false" is set. However, it also completely disables regular account logins it seems? This is a problem, as we do want to allow regular accounts for those of our users who can't/won't use Facebook for whatever reason. Existing accounts need to still be able to log in, and going forward our sysops team will be creating non-fb accounts for those users who need them.